# Audio recording from BT device (car radio/head unit) can cause automatic phone calls?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-audiomanager, android-audiorecord, android-audio-streams

In the latest update (which was recently) for one of my app (a video recorder) for Android smartphones I have added an option to record audio from a connected BT device. It can be done with the following function:

`AudioManager.startBluetoothSco()`

Today I have received the following review from one of my users:

> I start the app and recording and it starts making phone calls on my
> cars Bluetooth radio

The user's device is Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra on Android 14 (from Goolge Play Console) which he connects to his car radio I believe while he's driving his car

Can it be related? And why does it happen? My app doesn't have any code to make phone calls, only `AudioManager.startBluetoothSco()/AudioManager.stopBluetoothSco()` was added in the latest update when I start/stop recording with `MediaRecorder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this is definitely caused by `AudioManager.startBluetoothSco()` when a smartphone is connected to a Car Radio (Head Unit) by Bluetooth.

Insane... I hate some Google's Android's developers.

Another review from one of my users when this option is enabled:

> If enabled, then my Head Unit constantly emulates a call to number
> 100000 from the dialer built into the Head Unit. At the same time, through
> the “phone” shortcut from the main Android Auto screen in the Head Unit, you
> can normally make and receive calls from the phone book. But the music
> no longer plays, since that pseudo-call is supposedly going on. Samsung A52s + Mitsubishi Outlander III
> (2021)

p.s.:
When you are using this option on a smartphone which is connected to just some BT Headset then it works fine and audio is being recorded normally from this BT device instead of phone's built-in mic